# Python Mongodb simple query

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to python and mongo db, i have a dict called data and i wanna use the keys to query the database called db.

```
def update_db(data, db):
for key in data:
    x=db.find({'label':key})
    for a in x:
        print a
```

I get the error message that find() does not exist.

Anyone can give me input on my problem ?

Comment: You should search in collection, not in db

Comment: A `collection` is mongo's "version" of a table. You need to query against the actual collection and not the database. `db.collection_name.find()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `find` method in database object. You should search documents in some collection, not in database. Database has collections like SQL database has tables. Collections have documents, like SQL tables have rows of data. E.g. if you have *users* collection:

```
def update_db(data, db):
    for key in data:
         users = db.users
         matchedUsers = users.find({'label':key})
         for user in matchedUsers:
             print user
```

Future reading [PyMongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html)